# How to assign two different DataSources to two UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I have found numerous questions this regarding, however all proposed solutions seem to distinguish within the delegate methods to pick picker1 or picker2.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSArray *values = ( pickerView == picker1 ? values1 : values2 );
    return [values count];
}
```

However there seem to be a solution where you may assign two different datasources encapsulated in a separate file to achieve this without having to distinguish between the two pickers as described above as [solution b)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417350/92153).

This is now a bit confusing.  Let say I have a ViewController that I set as the FileOwner of the View with those two pickers.  Now if I create two separate interfaces that conform to the `<UIPickerViewDataSource>` and `<UIPickerViewDelegate>`, how do I bind the pickers from the view to these two interfaces?  Surely I can import them into my ViewController (FileOwner). But then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're creating the views in a xib/storyboard, the simplest thing to do would be to set up outlets for both views and set the datasources/delegates in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.myDataSource1 = [[MyDataSource1 alloc] init];
    self.myDataSource2 = [[MyDatasource2 alloc] init];

    self.pickerOne.delegate = self.myDataSource1;
    self.pickerOne.dataSource = self.myDataSource1;
    self.pickerTwo.delegate = self.myDataSource2;
    self.pickerTwo.dataSource = self.myDataSource2;
}
```

...where MyDataSource1 and MyDataSource 2 are the classes you've created to act as delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say MyClass conforms to picker datasource and delegate methods.
It also has below public properties.

```
@property NSInteger rows;
@property NSArray *data;
.... others properties that you set which you will return in delegate methods.
```

Now in ur view Controller,

```
MyClass *delegate1 = [MyClass alloc] init]
delegate1.rows = numberOfRowsInPicker1;
delegate1.data = picker1Data;
// set other public properties of delegate1
picker1.delegate=delegate1;
picker1.datasource=delegate1;
```

similarly delegate2 as delegate for picker2.